# How to log soap client messages with Spring using the Logback implementation of Slf4j

Tags: java, spring, web-services, logging, soap

How can i log all client side SOAP messages sent (and their responses) via webservice template using the **Logback** as the logging framework?

The answers i have seen so far, such as the:
[How can I make Spring WebServices log all SOAP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109251/how-can-i-make-spring-webservices-log-all-soap-requests)

refer either to commons logging, which i have excluded as dependency:

```
<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

, or endpoint logging.

If i understood correctly, i should provide implementation of interceptor which should be set as webservice template property.

Could someone show me code example how to do that?

Comment: Which logging provider used doesn't matter... Just set the same categories/loggers to trace or debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class LogbackInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogbackInterceptor .class);


     public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
           logger.debug("Sent request [" + messageContext.getRequest() + "]");
           return true;
     }

     public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
           logger.debug("Received response [" + messageContext.getResponse() + "] for request [" +
                                messageContext.getRequest() + "]");
           return true;
}

.....
}
```

However it isn't clear why just don't add `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` and follow with standard WS loggin option from that SO answer?..