# Spring: Logging outgoing HTTP requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I am trying to log all the outgoing Http requests in my spring based web application. Is there is interceptor for this purpose? I want to log all outgoing the contents and headers before it leaves the application. I am using `spring-ws` to send SOAP requests. So basically, I want to log not only the SOAP request xml (as mentioned here [How can I make Spring WebServices log all SOAP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109251/how-can-i-make-spring-webservices-log-all-soap-requests)) but the http request as a whole.

Comment: Have you considered using aop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intercept the request/response using a `ClientInterceptor` on the `WebServiceGatewaySupport`:

```
// soapClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport
soapClient.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{new ClientInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                messageContext.getRequest().writeTo(os);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new WebServiceIOException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            String request = new String(os.toByteArray());
            logger.trace("Request Envelope: " + request);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                messageContext.getResponse().writeTo(os);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new WebServiceIOException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            String response = new String(os.toByteArray());
            logger.trace("Response Envelope: " + response);
            return true;
        }
        ...
```

To get the headers as well you need an instance of `TransportOutputStream`.
Unfortunately the class is abstract, so you need to subclass is. Here's how it might look:

```
class ByteArrayTransportOutputStream extends TransportOutputStream {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;

    @Override
    public void addHeader(String name, String value) throws IOException {
        createOutputStream();
        String header = name + ": " + value + "\n";
        outputStream.write(header.getBytes());
    }

    public byte[] toByteArray() {
         return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected OutputStream createOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        }
        return outputStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this one. It only logs SOAP request xml. Not the HTTP request along with http headers.

Comment: You could pass a `TransportOutputStream` instead of a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. According to the Javadoc of `WebServiceMessage#writeTo`: If the given stream is an instance of {@link
     * org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportOutputStream}, the corresponding headers will be written as well.

Comment: How do I get the instance of `TransportOutputStream` here?

Comment: You need to subclass `TransportOutputStream` (there is no public implementation available that you could use).

Comment: I've added an example implementation that you could use.