# Pretty print spring-ws soap message in log

Tags: java, soap, log4j, slf4j, spring-ws

We are debugging some spring-ws soap web services and outputting the soap request using the log4j settings highlighted in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17605616/1279002

I would like to pretty print the soap message being sent to the log. Does anybody know if this can be done and if so how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

To print the SOAP message, 
Add `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor` interceptor provided by spring-ws. Also, set logging level to `DEBUG`.

Comment: Question specifically starts with "pretty print"