# How to handle incoming and outgoing SOAP XML Messages in Spring Boot

Tags: xml, spring, soap

I have a SOAP Client that works using `WebServiceGatewaySupport`. And it works as expected: it sends and retrieves XML Messages perfectly with marshalling features. But, now I want to handle that XML Messages in my service. I can only log traced messages of `WebServiceTemplate`. However, I need pure XML Messages that goes around the service. How to achieve that?

```
@Service
public class SampleGatewayClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    ...
    public SampleGatewayClient() {
        this.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        this.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        this.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
    }
    ...

    private ResponseObject sendAndRetrieveMessage() {
        ...
        // No control over sended and received messages!
        return (ResponseObject) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive(gatewayUri, requestPayload);
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109251/how-can-i-make-spring-webservices-log-all-soap-requests